# mysql support for multiple triggers on one table official docs

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a way to implement multiple triggers on one table in mysql but i have searchged for the official documentation on mysql's support for multiple triggers but i only seem to find an unofficial blog post on the topic here http://dmitryshulga.blogspot.com/2013/09/support-for-multiple-triggers-per-table.html

Has the topic of support of multiple triggers been documented yet?.

Comment: The MySQL Reference Manual does document this restriction; I know it's documented for version 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [CREATE TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) states:

> There cannot be multiple triggers for a given table that have the same
>   trigger event and action time. For example, you cannot have two BEFORE
>   UPDATE triggers for a table. **But you can have a BEFORE UPDATE and a
>   BEFORE INSERT trigger, or a BEFORE UPDATE and an AFTER UPDATE trigger.**

Emphasis by me.